# Unsure where image_write downloads to in shinyapps.io

Tags: r, shinyapps

I'm attempting to make a public shinyapps.io website, and I'm trying to use image_write to create a file into a local directory.

The following code works on my local R studio code:

```
image_write(im.resized, path = paste0(output_file_directory, file_name), format = "jpg")
```

When I run the code on the shinyapps.io website, the code runs without error, but I'm not sure where it downloads the file to. I know that the output_file_directory part isn't the issue, so I'm a little lost. Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

On shinyapps.io it is not possibly to store permanently data, due to:

"Shinyapps.io is a popular server for hosting Shiny apps. It is designed to distribute your Shiny app across different servers, which means that if a file is saved during one session on some server, then loading the app again later will probably direct you to a different server where the previously saved file doesn’t exist."

See here:
https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/persistent-data-storage.html